# How is it possible that $\Delta y = dy$ for infinitesimally small $dx$?

Tags: calculus

I see on the graph (see below) and I can't see how $\Delta y = dy$ for infinitesimally small $dx$. $dy$ belongs to tangent line which touches the graph at only one point $A$.

I assume it's possible if we take $\Delta y1$ instead $\Delta y$ and then $\Delta y1=dy$ and so on for infinitesimally small $dx$. Is it right?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You may want to really clarify firstly *what* "Δ=  for infinitesimally small " *means*, before asking *why* or *how*. Unless you go to the formalism of [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis), there is no "infinitesimally small" quantity in real analysis.

Comment: I'm not really a fan of the labelling on this diagram. You should never think of $\Delta x$ as equal to "$dx$": at this level of calculus, "$dx$" isn't even a properly defined thing (it gets a proper definition later on in differential geometry, as sections of the cotangent bundle, but that's jumping really far ahead). $\Delta x$ is just a number, same with $\Delta y$, only that $\Delta y$ is dependent on $\Delta x$. What's important is that their *ratio*, $\Delta y/\Delta x$, *approaches* $dy/dx$ as $\Delta x$ tends to zero, which is "kinda like saying" $\Delta x\to dx$ and $\Delta y\to dy$.

Comment: Just remember $dy/dx$ is simply fancy (and intuitively quite helpful) notation for the derivative. It's not an actual ratio of numbers or anything, although it happens to be the *limit* of a ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a function represents the rate of the change of the function values with respect to its argument. The tangent represents the approximation of the function in the immediate neighborhood of the point of tangency (more accurately for an infinitesimal neighborhood) because it has same rate change.

Then as the function values scale the $y-axis$ , the $dy$ on the tangent would be the same as the $\Delta y$ of the function value(same rate of change for a given $\Delta x$),while by the pythagorean theorem,$\Delta y_1$ would be the hypotenuse,that is $\sqrt{\Delta y^2+ \Delta x ^2}$